# Chrome extension to block websites that I can easily turn off

Tags: chrome, website-blocker

I would like a website blocking extension for Google Chrome that lets me turn it off with some, but not much, friction without having to go to the extensions menu every time I toggle it.

My specific situation is that I already know to use blockers for sites where I am never productive, like Facebook. However, I frequently read StackExchange sites for fun, but also need to access them for my work. As a result, I can't block SE in most website blockers, but I still squander a lot of time on the sites.

What I would like is a blocker I could use specifically for the sites I use both for work and procrastination. It should have some functionality similar to:

- A button in the toolbar that turns it on and off.
- When I click the button to turn it off, I have to complete a slightly difficult task, like retyping a short block of text.
- When I click the button to turn it on, it does so immediately.

Then, I could use one blocker for most sites and this blocker for SE. This allows me to easily access SE when I need to, but makes it just difficult enough for me to access SE when I want to procrastinate that it will be easier to convince myself to get to work.

Comment: There's also [uBlock](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock) for Chromium.

Answer (score 2):

A quick Google Search lead me to the extension called Block Site, reviews for the app are solid and has a user base of 400,000+, and is rated 4/5.

[Block site](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/block-site/eiimnmioipafcokbfikbljfdeojpcgbh?hl=en) is a tool made just for this purpose.

Features:

- Right click on a site to (un)block it
- Neat Interface
- Free
- Easy to use

Answer (score 2):

I use the extension [Blocker](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blocker/jphfnnacagbhfelldlccmiocmdodnlio) to accomplish this.

It fulfills your requirements, the difficulty of the task required to turn it off (typing a random alphanumeric string) is configurable, and about the only improvement I can imagine for it would be not having to disable it to add a new site to the list.

I assume you have to disable it so you don't remove URLs from the list to get around the string entry disabling task, but it would be nice to be able to add new URLs (ie, when you realize a site that isn't on the blocklist is distracting you and Blocker is activated).

Other than that, though, it's perfect, and sounds like just what you are looking for.

Comment: Unfortunately, Blocker is no longer available on the Chrome Web Store.